# TypeScript: check object attribute is of custom type

Tags: typescript

I have this type:

```
type APhoto = (StrapiMedia | Photo)
```

`StrapiMedia` and `Photo` are both interfaces that come from other packages. I need to check if something is of type `APhoto`. Something similar to:

```
for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] instanceof APhoto[]) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

But the instaceof operation is invlaid, I get the syntax error `'APhoto' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

How can I solve this type check?

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions to this issue. The first way is using a typeguard and the second way is just using a key in object check.

Check here for more information regarding Advanced types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

## Typeguard Example

```
type Photo = {
  url: string;
  format: string;
  encoding: string;
};

type StrapiMedia = {
  url: string;
  format: string;
  metadata: unknown;
};

type APhoto = StrapiMedia | Photo;

// Typeguard

function isStrapiMedia(item: APhoto): item is StrapiMedia {
  return (item as StrapiMedia).metadata !== undefined;
}

function doSomething(item: APhoto) {
  if (isStrapiMedia(item)) {
    console.log(item.metadata); // StrapiMedia
  } else {
    console.log(item.encoding); // Photo
  }
}
```

### Key in object check example

```
type Photo = {
  url: string;
  format: string;
  encoding: string;
};

type StrapiMedia = {
  url: string;
  format: string;
  metadata: unknown;
};

type APhoto = StrapiMedia | Photo;

// Key in object check

function doSomething(item: APhoto) {
  if ("metadata" in item) {
    console.log(item.metadata); // StrapiMedia
  } else {
    console.log(item.encoding); // Photo
  }
}
```

And in this scenario when you want to iterate through a collection you can replace the `doSomething` with the following (uses key in object example):

```
function doSomething(items: APhoto[]) {
  for (var item of items) {
    if ("metadata" in item) {
      console.log(item.metadata); // StrapiMedia
    } else {
      console.log(item.encoding); // Photo
    }
  }
}
```